# Suite CRM: Where the verification with database exists?

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using suite CRM. I need information from an expert.

Where can I find the function that verifies the existence of a field in the database before saving a form?

The scenario I have is to save a new opportunity. After choosing an account from the pop up list, I try to save the new opportunity, but I get an error:

> "No match, field doesn't exist".

I found a peice of code in cache\include\javascript\sugar_grp1 :

```
function validate_form(formname, startsWith) {
    requiredTxt = SUGAR.language.get('app_strings', 'ERR_MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS');
    invalidTxt = SUGAR.language.get('app_strings', 'ERR_INVALID_VALUE');
    if (typeof(formname) == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
```

I want to find where the verification with the database is done, any one could give me any information?

Comment: As side-note: If you do a "Quick Repair and Rebuild" and scroll down on the resulting output, there might be some SQL at the end for fixing missing fields. Run the SQL via the button or manually if necessary and repeat the process until no fields are missing anymore.

Also you might need to do Repair -> Repair Relationships and such.

(Info based on SugarCRM)

Comment: i tried it, doesn't work, the error i get is No match for field: Account Name  , it appeared after i added an auto poulated field (country) which is autopopulated after choosing an account.

Comment: i didn't find also a script when runing quick repair the last phrase was Database tables are synced with vardefs

Comment: Can you check the database and see if your new field is there? It will be in opportunities_cstm.

Comment: yes i found a column in opportunities_cstm

Comment: Is the field in the validate array in your browser? This can achieved using the function *addToValidate(formname, name, type, required, msg)* method found in *jssource/src_files/include/javascript/sugar_3.js*

The validate_form process the items in the validate array.

Comment: "Is the field in the validate array in your browser?" how can i verify if it is